# Windows Azure in Turkey

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am in turkey and I tried to create a Windows Azure account but on the region selection, Turkey is not listed. So, does that mean I am stuck here or is it possible to have a Windows Azure Account by selecting another country name. e.g. United Kingdom.

I am not so familiar with azure but our company customer's profile is mostly UK based. Does Azure run the apps according to end-users' geolocation?

Comment: I have seen that 3 votes to close this topic. that's mean !

Comment: it is saying that ***Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to programming or software development in some way, within the scope defined in the faq*** isn't this related to programming? come on people !

Comment: can anybody tell me how this question is off-topic?

Comment: closing the question and not leaving any comment is not so informative. guys who closed this topic have nearly no azure tag on their profile anyway.

Comment: @tugberk I don't really agree with this being closed, but... I suggest you post *Does Azure run the apps according to end-users' geolocation?* as another question. That should be legit either here or on serverfault.com...

Comment: @tugberk Another alternative would be to ask this question on MSDN forums for Windows Azure. There is one forum dedicated for purchasing: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazurepurchasing/threads.

Comment: Azure now available in Turkey. Azure in 89 Countries check out [Azure FAQ](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/faq/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FAQ on the Azure site states that azure is available in 41 countries currently. I don't see turkey listed as one of those countries. I would assume that means you are out of luck.

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/faq/default.aspx

Of course you can select a different country but I assume they use these sorts of things for billing purposes so that might be an issue.

Comment: thanks for the answer. do you know that does azure run the apps according to end-users' geolocation?

Comment: not sure what you mean by that. The app would live on your Azure instance and could be served to users in different geo-locations. The geographic restrictions I believe are just limited to the account owner / billing address

Comment: I mean like CDNs. let's say I have an azure account and I am currently in the UK. I have set up my web apps and they are running. what happens when a user comes to my web app from India? wiil it be like CDNs?

Comment: Azure offers a CDN product that you can leverage if you want. http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/cdn/default.aspx